# How to get all parameter names along with their values in stored procedure which is being executed

Tags: stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012, is there any possible way to get all the parameters of a stored procedure along with the values passed to it?

I need these things to build a xml. I mean this should happen in the procedure which being executed and it should be common for all the procedures.

For example, let us suppose we have to procedures,

1. `uspSave, @name='test' @age=20`
2. `uspDelete @id=2`

now in `uspSave` procedure, I need to get `@name, @age` and the values 'test', 20
and in `uspDelete`, I should get `@id` with value 2.

For getting the column names, I tried this,

```
select parameter_name 
from information_schema.PARAMETERS 
where specific_name = OBJECT_NAME(@@procid)
```

now is it possible to loop through the result of above query and can we get the values.

Comment: Could you clarify the "why" - what is your end goal/purpose?

Comment: my goal is to build an xml out of these parameters with their values and when an error occurs, i have to save this xml in the error table

Comment: T-SQL isn't a language rich with reflection-like facilities. It's practically impossible to write re-usable code as you seem to be aiming for.

Comment: ya many be, but we already have the parameter name, cant we get the value using dynamic sql, i mean trying something like this => declare @Id int; exec sp_executesql N'select @Id';

Comment: As mentioned in your question if your problem is only looping then cursor might be helpful.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: @Rain, i can loop through the parameter names, but how do i get the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use some code generation to generate the code block you require.

i.e.

- Create your sproc without the code to XML-ify the parameters
- Knock up a quick script (could be done in TSQL) to then construct the sproc-specific block of TSQL to convert the parameters into XML, using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS
- Copy that bit of auto-generated script into your sproc

The way you were thinking with dynamic sql wouldn't work because of the scope - the parameters would not be accessible within that dynamically generated SQL, you'd need to pass them in as args via sp_executesql, which puts you back in square 1.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @someval int = 7
EXECUTE('SELECT @someval') -- @someval is not in scope
```

So, if it will help save time, then code gen looks like your best bet.

Comment: ya man, that is exactly what i wanted, but too bad the limitation of the exec statement stopped the whole approach. anyways i tried to generate the xml by manually passing the parameter values, i guess thats the only way.